# How can I promote code reuse in a manner similar to mixins/method modifiers/traits in other languages?

Tags: haskell, code-reuse

I'm working on some code that interfaces to a database schema that models a persistent graph. Before I go into the details of my specific question, I thought it might help to provide some motivation. My schema is around books, people and author roles. A book has many author roles, where each role has a person. However, instead of allowing direct UPDATE queries on book objects, you must create a new book, and make modifications to the new version.

Now, back to Haskell land. I am currently working with a few type classes, but importantly I have `HasRoles` and `Entity`:

```
class HasRoles a where
    -- Get all roles for a specific 'a'
    getRoles :: a -> IO [Role]

class Entity a where
    -- Update an entity with a new entity. Return the new entity.
    update :: a -> a -> IO a
```

Here comes my problem. When you are updating a book, you need to create a new book version but you *also* need to copy over the previous books roles (otherwise you lose data). The simplest way to do this is:

```
instance Entity Book where
    update orig newV = insertVersion V >>= copyBookRoles orig
```

This is fine, but there's something that bugs me, and that's the lack of any guarantee of the invariant that if something is an `Entity` *and* `HasRoles`, then inserting a new version will copy over the existing roles. I have thought of 2 options:

### Use More Types

One 'solution' is to introduce the `RequiresMoreWork a b`. Going from the above, `insertVersion` now returns a `HasRoles w => RequiresMoreWork w Book`. `update` wants a `Book`, so to get out of the `RequiresMoreWork` value, we could call `workComplete :: RequiresMoreWork () Book -> Book` .

The real problem with this though, is that the most important piece of the puzzle is the type signature of `insertVersion`. If this doesn't match the invariants (for example, it made no mention of needing `HasRoles`) then it all falls apart again, and we're back to violating an invariant.

### Prove it with QuickCheck

Moves the problem out of compile time, but at least we're still asserting the invariant. In this case, the invariant is something like: for all entities that are also instances of `HasRoles`, inserting a new version of an existing value should have the same roles.

---

I'm a bit stumped on this. In Lisp I'd use method modifiers, in Perl I'd use roles, but is there anything I can use in Haskell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm of two minds as to how I should respond to this:

> This is fine, but there's something that bugs me, and that's the lack
>   of any guarantee of the invariant that if something is an Entity and
>   HasRoles, then inserting a new version will copy over the existing
>   roles.

One the one hand, if something is an Entity, it doesn't matter if it HasRoles or not.  You simply provide the update code, and it should be correct for that specific type.

On the other, this does mean that you'll be reproducing the `copyRoles` boilerplate for each of your types and you certainly could forget to include it, so it's a legitimate problem.

When you require dynamic dispatch of this nature, one option is to use a GADT to scope over the class context:

```
class Persisted a where
    update :: a -> a -> IO a

data Entity a where
    EntityWithRoles :: (Persisted a, HasRoles a) => a -> Entity a
    EntityNoRoles   :: (Persisted a) => a -> Entity a

instance Persisted (Entity a) where
    insert (EntityWithRoles orig) (EntityWithRoles newE) = do
      newRoled <- copyRoles orig newE
      EntityWithRoles <$> update orig newRoled
    insert (EntityNoRoles orig) (EntityNoRoles newE) = do
      EntityNoRoles <$> update orig newE
```

However, given the framework you've described, rather than having an `update` class method, you could have a `save` method, with `update` being a normal function

```
class Persisted a where
    save :: a -> IO ()

-- data Entity as above

update :: Entity a -> (a -> a) -> IO (Entity a)
update (EntityNoRoles orig) f = let newE = f orig in save newE >> return (EntityNoRoles newE)
update (EntityWithRoles orig) f = do
  newRoled <- copyRoles orig (f orig)
  save newRoled
  return (EntityWithRoles newRoled)
```

I would expect some variation of this to be much simpler to work with.

A major difference between type classes and OOP classes is that type class methods don't provide any means of code re-use.  In order to re-use code, you need to pull the commonalities out of type class methods and into functions, as I did with `update` in the second example.  An alternative, which I used in the first example, is to convert everything into some common type (`Entity`) and then only work with that type.  I expect the second example, with a standalone `update` function, would be simpler in the long run.

There is another option that may be worth exploring.  You could make `HasRoles` a superclass of Entity and require that all your types have `HasRoles` instances with dummy functions (e.g. `getRoles _ = return []`).  If most of your entities would have roles anyway, this is actually pretty convenient to work with and it's completely safe, although somewhat inelegant.

Comment: Well, this is all nice, but I'm still not happy with it. For example, it looks like the GADT needs to be all possible combinations of "parts" of an entity. For example, right now they have roles, but I imagine in the future some entities will have other data that needs to be managed in a similar way (tags, ratings, for example). It feels like I'd need EntityWithRoles, EntityWithTags, EntityWithRolesAndTags, etc. Pretty horrible!

Comment: The bounty closes today, so I'm going to accept this answer and give you the bounty, as it's still been enlightening, and I'll see what the cafe have to say :)

Comment: If the `ConstraintKinds` extension (http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=127) gets added to ghc, I think that would solve this problem in a more elegant way.  Until then, I would probably take the path I suggested in the last paragraph.  It's safe, simple, and it works.

Answer (score 4):

Dealing in the specific, I would make the roles part of a type instead of an class

data Rolled a = Rolled a [Role]

instance Entity a => Entity (Rolled a) 
   where update (Rolled a rs) = Rolled (update a) rs

More generally, you could just make pairs instances of Entity

I haven't reached haskell zen, but I would guess you should end up working in the Writer or State monad (or their transformer versions)

Comment: If you take this approach, I would highly recommend fclabels (or a similar package) to make lenses for updating the various components of both `Rolled` and the various entities.